# MYSQL QUERY SUM with date

Tags: mysql, date, sum, resultset

Currently my output for my query is that:

```
  code  | name     |datein    |dateexpire| type    | qty
  code01| computer |2015-08-01|2015-10-01|computer |2
  code02| mouse    |2015-08-01|2015-10-01|mouse    |1
  code03| printer  |2015-08-01|2015-10-01|printer  |3 (I want 1)
```

My problem , I want printer display 1 because I want to filter with dates interval,for example I have an **userA** get in 2015-10-01, so there is 1 printer , if an userB get in 2015-08-01, it will have 2 printer because : 
I have 2 printers available:

```
    printer1|2015-08-01|2015-08-24 <-- user B
    printer3|2015-08-01|2015-10-02 <--- **only 1 for userA who get in 2015-10-01**
```

How can I output for the main query printer equal to 1 and not 3 .

Comment: please explain clearly..

Comment: as you can see i have got 3 printer, but userA will only get 1 printer if I sum by type (currently it 's sum all printer so 3, it's not why I expect)

Comment: your question is confusing. You have 3 rows as i can see. So when user enters date 01-10-2015 then what we have to show? if user enter date 01-08-2015 then what we have to show? With which columnshould we compare date ?

Comment: if user enter date 01-08-2015 and exit 01-10-2015 he will have 2 printer if user user enter 01-10-2010 and exit 31-12-2015 he will have 1 printer

Comment: how do we determine this if we need to give 2 printer or 1 printer?

Comment: with the date expire of printer, if dateexpir is include on user end , it will be add to user, for example ,userB enter in 01-08-2015 and exit 30-09-2015 , so he will have 2 printer (look the expiration date of printer), and userA enter 01-10-2015 so he will have 1 printer

Comment: this is totally confusing still. Do you need to write it in single query? Are we going to update qty column when use enter date 01-08-2015 and exit 30-09-2015

Comment: No updating , just select , I think need to create subquery for date range and a specific type ,here type printer

Comment: what happens if user enters 01-08-2015 and exit 30-08-2015... how do we determine how many printers he will have

Comment: he will have 2 printer, the start date is important

Comment: on what basis you calculated 2?

Comment: the start date is important

Comment: There is no logic with your query which we can apply. Do we read your mind and decide what to display?